# C#: Interface implementation structures and overriding

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, overriding

I have a C# solution with this structure:

- Project 1: Contains a Dao (can contain more than one)
- Project 2: Contains an interface (only one)
- Project 3: A wcf service with its    own interface
- The dao in project 1 implements the interface in project 2.
- The wcf service interface in project 3 implements/inherits/entends the interface in project 2.

The problem I have is that the interface in project 2 is needed to describe my dao class(s). The wcf interface is needed to describe what functions are available in my wcf service in project 3. The two interfaces are exactly the same, apart from the wcf attributes being on the wcf interface, because all the functions in the dao need to be exposed by the wcf service file too. The implementation or rather the dao class can be changed/swapped out but must always follow the same structure hence the need for an interface. Now with these two interfaces being identical when I try to implement it in my wcf interface I am told I must effectively override all of the methods in the interface I am deriving from. Is this the correct thing to do? The wcf interface needs to implement the interface from project 2 so that it provides all the functions we need from the dao (which is all of them).

Previously I had the project set up as follows:

- Project 1: Contains the dao
- Project 2: Contains an interface with wcf
  attributes as well
- Project 3: Contains no interface but just the wcf
  service

Both the dao and the wcf service implemented the same interface from project 2. Would having the wcf attributes on the interface have had any adverse effects when using it with the dao? One issue I may have is that the wcf interface may eventually have extra functions that the base interface does not and so I think this previous structure would have been wrong. Truth be told I have no idea.

I know I am probably not explaining it very clearly and there are actually two or even three questions involved here but it is the best way to put it across. I guess my three main questions are as follows:

1. Which inheritance/implementation structure would be best and why?
2. Would implementing the same interface used by a wcf service in a
   normal class have any ill effects (caused by the wcf attributes i.e. [ServiceContract], [OperationContract]).
3. Would overriding all of the methods provided by a base interface be
   correct?

Comment: why the dao is implementing the interface? what benefit you can get from it, implementing the same interface. Since IMHO interfaces are contracts meant to comply certain business logic, not exactly the data access.

Comment: Because I want an interface that will describe a dao of a certain type and the methods it should have. It is just simple programming to interfaces. I may have more than one dao that implements this interface and I want them all to definetly have the same methods which will make them interchangeable so that the wcf service can access them in a uniform manner no matter which dao is used. I would use the line IClusterQueryService foo = new MyDao() where MyDao implements the interface. This means I can use any dao so long as it implements the IClusterQueryService interface.

Comment: Agreed 100% but my question was why the DAO has same interface as the business exposes to outside world as WCF service, should not these two be different?

Comment: Well usually I guess they would be different but my interface and dao were designed before the wcf was introduced and it just so happened that all of the functions within the dao actually needed to be exposed via the wcf so both interfaces (one to describe a dao and one for the wcf) happened to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure you first defined is fine, you have an interface that implements an interface and the child interface can add new methods that aren't in the base. However, you don't need to define the base methods in the child interface because they are all inherited so right now your child interface would be empty. And in this model the child interface can have the WCF attributes.

Now, are you going to have to implement all of those methods in the WCF service? Quite simply yes because that's what interfaces do - they define a contract that must be implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One thing I dont understand. In the scenario given in solution one would I put the wcf attributes on the parent/base interface? Are the attributes inherited along with the methods themselves? I ask because if the wcf attributes are not present then I cannot use it as a wcf interface and unless I override the methods in the child interface I cannot add the attributes after implementing the parent so they need to come from somewhere.

Comment: The WCF attributes go on the child interface. The one that inherits from the other one. That's the correct place to put them because if you were going to expose new methods that aren't in the other interface you'd do it from there.

Comment: So are you saying that I should override the methods from the parent interface in order to add the attributes to those too as I currently need all the methods from the parent interface to be exposed as wcf methods. Sorry if I am coming across as daft but I want to be sure I am understanding correctly

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you're saying, well I would say you're going to have to do something I wouldn't generally recommend. Make the base interface a ServiceContract and all of the methods an OperationContract. I'm not saying that service contracts shouldn't inherit one another - but the base interface was originally meant for something else and is now being grafted in. You can also override the methods if you like - but by putting attributes on both it will work like a real interface.